# Prove that $g$ is also continuous at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. For any $r\in\mathbb{R}$, define $g(x) = f(rx)\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $g$ is also continuous at $x=0$.

Proof:
If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then
$$\forall \epsilon\;\exists \delta\; s.t\;|x-0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$$
Let $x = ry$.
$$\forall \epsilon\;\exists \delta\; s.t\;|ry-0|<\delta \implies |f(ry)-f(0)|<\epsilon$$
$$\therefore g(y)=f(ry) \text{ is continuous at } y=0.$$
Is this proof correct ? If not please explain how to prove the result.

Comment: You have the right idea, although normally, we would say something like, for any $y$ such that $|y| < \delta/r$, then $g(y) = f(ry)$ satisfies $|g(y) - g(0)| = |f(ry)-f(0)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: If you do not insist on "$\epsilon - \delta$", then more simple is use concept of composition of 2 continuous functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You did not prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies|g(x)-g(0)|<\varepsilon$.

If $r=0$, then the statement is trivial. Otherwise, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\eta>0$ such that $|x|<\eta\implies|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$. Let $\delta=\frac\eta{|r|}$. Then\begin{align}|x|<\delta&\iff|rx|<\eta\\&\implies|f(rx)-f(0)|<\varepsilon\\&\iff|g(x)-g(0)|<\varepsilon.\end{align}